# Zurb Foundation 5 open modal with javascript close with close-reveal-modal

Tags: javascript, web, zurb-foundation

I have a link on my page that enables the user to open a modal - the code for this is:

```html
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="edit-valuation-variation-item-modal-{{$variation_item->id}}">{{ $valuation_variation_items[$variation_item->id] }}</a>
```

When the modal has appears the user can click the [X] button to close the it. This is very standard out of the box stuff that simply uses a html 'a' tag with a class of close-reveal-modal like so:

```html
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
```

This is all well and good.

However, there are cases in which i need to use Javascript to automatically display the modal, and in order to do this I use the following standard out of the box code:

```js
$('#edit-valuation-variation-item-modal-269').foundation('reveal', 'open', {
  animation: 'none',
  close_on_background_click: false,
  dismiss_modal_class: 'close-reveal-modal'
});
```

This works fine. However, when a modal is displayed this way, when the user clicks the [X] to close the modal - the modal closes but then the link on the page is no longer active, it wont reopen the modal as before. If i refresh the browser window all appears to reset and start working again.

Can anyone suggest how to re-enable the button to open the modal without refreshing the page.

I should add in order to reduct the code in the question the above code demonstrates a single link where as my page contains a number of links that do the same each with a different modal-Number - all of these links are affected and become unusable.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in your javascript console? I would wager that when clicking the [x], after hiding, it removes the modal altogether, so that your link can no longer use it.

Comment: Not that I can see. It "disables" all links on the page. The cursor recognises the links in that the cursor changes but the links are unresponsive.

Comment: Can you paste all the relavent JS into the question? Or into a http://paste.ee/ bin and post the link here? Cheers. Including the bit where you call `$(document).foundation();`

Comment: Hi @DanielMatthews i have uploaded the code here: http://paste.ee/p/jwMlu  . Thanks.